# ngModel is not working when an input field is repeated with the property inside the repeated array's object is used in [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm actually repeating an mat input field and then I have written [(ngModel)] with the property name of the object in the array as [(ngModel)]'s value

For example this is the array of objects that I have :

```
test = [{name: 'Harish'},{name: 'Pushpa'}]
```

So in the html I repeated this array as below :

```
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" *ngFor="let i of test"> 
<input  matInput placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]='i.name' name='trtrtrtrt'>


</mat-form-field>
```

But it is showing the value of all the input field's as the name of the last element in the array

Here's the working [plunker](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjvhu5?embed=1&file=app/input-overview-example.html&view=editor) of the issue that I'm getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different `input` should has different `name` property.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" *ngFor="let i of test"> 
    <input  matInput placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]='i.name' [name]='i.name'>
</mat-form-field>
```

You can find the result in [plunker](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjvhu5-h7rgat)

Answer (score 2):

I had very similar issue (in angular 7) - could not trace down in the stack why this was happening when in other components exactly the same code worked.  My workaround for two-way binding was:

```
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" *ngFor="let i of test"> 
    <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" [value]="i.name"  (input)="i.name = $event.target.value" [name]='i.name'>   
  </mat-form-field>
```

i.e. using the [value] and (input) bindings.

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks. Worked well.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" *ngFor="let i of test"> 
<input  matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="{{i.name}}" name='trtrtrtrt'>   
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: value is working fine, but I want to use two way data binding here

Comment: @you can not do it in using loop

Comment: How do I do that? Can you edit the plunker that I posted in the question  and show me?

Comment: @pushplatapatel let me figure out.

Comment: Sure, will wait for your answer

Comment: the key point is all `input` have the same `name`. Make them different, it will work.

Comment: check this @pushplatapatel

Comment: name='trtrtrtrt' will keep same name for all textboxes. This will not work. Please double check.